# How to handle Java freezing upon executing Statement.executeQuery()?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hello I am writing an application that runs in Java and talks through JDBC to a MySQL database. The problem I am having is that this application is a real-time application and the connection to the database going down at some point is inevitable. Here is a sketch of the code:

```
int result          = 0;
Statement st        = null;
ResultSet rs        = null;
System.out.println("Obatining reference to main connection");
Connection conne    = Main.connection;
try {
    System.out.println("In try");
    System.out.println("Creating statement");
    st = conne.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Obtaining result");
    rs = st.executeQuery("Properly constructed and tested sql query");
    rs.last();
    result = rs.getRow();
    System.out.println("Exiting try");
}catch(SQLException se){ 
    se.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    System.out.println("In finally");
    try { rs.close();    } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
    try { st.close();    } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
}
  return result;
```

The program freezes after printing Obtaining Result. If the connection is active everything runs just fine but I need to protect it from the database going down. The way that I am testing this is to disconnect from the database right before I run this method.There are no exceptions thrown nor errors generated. Once its prints Obtaining Result the program simply hangs. I was hoping that someone knew a way to recover from this scenario? Again the application runs perfectly but I need to be able to recover from the database being unavailable.

More information:

By disconnect I mean that I am connecting to the database through a vpn and shutting the vpn down in order to make the database unavailable.

Someone had posted that the SQL is not properly formated. Allow me to clarify, that is not the actual SQL statement. Id rather not put the actual statement in and it isn't actually relevant as any valid statement produces the same undesired effects.

Comment: we need to see the sql statement you are running.

Comment: It could be any SQL statement. The statement itself isn't causing the problem. Even the most basic and fool-proof cause the halt in execution without termination of the program.

Comment: Apologies for not being a mind-reader.

Comment: No need for apologies if anything I owe you one. If I came across as angry it was not my intention. I was trying to assure you that the SQL itself is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do the database work on a background thread.  This makes it possible to wait a specified amount of time and then proceed along if the time expires.

The easiest way to get started is with an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).  You can submit individual tasks, and wait on the returned [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) for a specific amount of time.  Also check out the  [invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method and friends.

You can also try using a [statement timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout%28int%29), although that may be less reliable than the Executor approach if there are driver bugs or unexpected communications issues (for example, a query that executes quickly but takes a long time to transfer its results).

Answer (score 0):

Is this a desktop application or a Java EE application?

If it's a desktop application, you could try making your database interactions be a thread, and set a timeout to them.

If it's a Java EE application, and you are not willing to use any frameworks, you can take a look at some Transaction libraries, and implement an explicit control over your internal transactions (such as adding a timeout to them). A starting point: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/ebeans/ch08_05.htm

Comment: Thanks for the information. It runs own its own server handling a series of calculations throughout the day. I am willing to look into anything that fixes the problem.